# Itemwise Proportion

Tags: summation

I have to calculate efficiency of some machines in our factory. The calculation process is per roll production base, that means when a roll comes out, we calculate efficiency of that roll. These efiiciency is two kinds, counter based and production based.I am supplying some data here,

`TargetQty   ProdQty PEff    Target_Counter  Complete_Counter    CEff
36.71712    21.25   57.87   3416.00          1977.01            57.88
30.39696    25.70   84.55   2828.00          2391.02            84.55
32.20272    23.20   72.04   2996.00          2158.43            72.04
28.59120    23.70   82.89   2660.00          2204.94            82.89
77.04576    24.95   32.38   7168.00          2321.24            32.38
71.92944    22.60   31.42   6692.00          2102.60            31.42
98.71488    19.05   19.30   9184.00          1772.33            19.30
6.98856     25.00   357.73  740.00           2647.18            357.73
11.29990    11.75   103.98  1518.00          1578.47            103.98
25.05630    18.70   74.63   3366.00          2512.11            74.63`

========================================================================
418.94284   215.9            40568           21665.33

Okay, that my data. Now in the table we see that each roll's PEff( Production Efficiency) AND CEff( Counter Efficiency) is same. But when I sum all rows and calculate both efficiency,
PEff=(215.9/418.94284)*100= 51.534%

AND CEff=(21665.33/40568)*100= 53.4049 %

!! Both are different now. But they are same in Per role calculation. How can I solve this problem? I need to equal both efficiencies. Please help if you can.

Comment: Something's a bit fishy with your last three rows. For all the other rows `Target_Counter/TargetQty = 93.04`, but for the third to last row `Target_Counter/TargetQty = 105.89` and the last two rows `Target_Counter/TargetQty = 134.34`. So the weights of the rows different when you calculate overall PEff and CEff, causing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gross CEff use the below formula

**Gross CEff = SUM(Complete_Counter)/SUM(Target_Counter)*{SUM(Target_Counter)*SUM(ProdQty)}/{SUM(Complete_Counter)*SUM(TargetQty)}**

Comment: Thanks moriarty for thinking... but I have a problem, I can't mix target_counter complete_counter with target_production complete production. These counter and Prod based eff should be seperate. Any Idea?